# WPF context menu doesn't stay open

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, contextmenu

In WPF I am trying to put a context menu on the items of a listbox. When I run my app and right click on an item of the listbox the menu pops up for a split second and then closes again. I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is the code I am using:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Name="lsbAddedElements" Width="150" Margin="3,3,3,3"
         SelectionMode="Multiple">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="btnDeleteElement_Click"></MenuItem>
          </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

The listbox is bound to an ObservableCollection in code when the window is initialised, so item management is taken care of in code behind.

UPDATE:

I might need to add that thsi is part of an adin I am making for Excel. I am connecting to Excel using ExcelDNA then passsing the handle on to the WPF window that this code snippet is part of.
Could this be a reason for the context menu behaving in an unexpected way?

Comment: did you try debugging with something like <ContextMenu ContextMenuClosing="closingEvent" /> - with a breakpoint set on that event. Also maybe check the stack as well

Comment: Following your suggestion I did, and the breakpoint doesn't get hit (neither does a breakpoint set on the ContextMenuOpening event handler). Weird.

Comment: Please share your itemtemplate of ListView

Comment: Code you have shared worked just fine for me!

Comment: HichemC, really? That sucks, because that would mean there is something wrong with my installation of VS :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the listbox item is getting focused. A simple solution to your problem is to set the context menu on the list box and enable/disable context menu items if the list box has a selected item.